# Conversion of uintptr_t into bool slows down SSO benchmark several times

Tags: c++, performance, type-conversion, benchmarking, microbenchmark

Consider the following class that implements (very basically for the sake of MCVE) *small string optimization* (assuming little endian, 64 bit pointers, etc.):

```
class String {
   char* data_;
   bool sso() const { return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(data_) & 1; }     
 public:
    String(const char * arg = "") {
       auto len = strlen(arg);
       if (len > 6) {
          data_ = new char[len + 1];
          memcpy(data_, arg, len + 1);
       } 
       else {
          data_ = reinterpret_cast<char*>((uintptr_t)1);
          memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data_) + 1, arg, len + 1);
       }            
   }  
   ~String() { if (sso() == false) delete data_; }
// ~String() { if (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(data_) & 1 == 0) delete data_; }
};
```

Note that there are 2 versions of the destructor. When I measured the difference between these 2 versions with Quick C++ Benchmark:

```
static void CreateShort(benchmark::State& state) {    
   for (auto _ : state) {    
      String s("hello");
      benchmark::DoNotOptimize(s); 
   }  
}
```

I got **5.7 times faster** running time in the second case with GCC. I don't understand why the compiler cannot generate the same optimized assembly here. What hinders compiler optimizations in case the result of bitwise AND operation is additionally converted into bool? (Though I am not an assembler expert, I can see some differences in the assembly outputs for both variants, but cannot figure out why there are there.)

- Benchmark link: http://quick-bench.com/wZhYuffRc1LMwFJ4rx4Xxy330Sw
- Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/dAUI_u

With Clang, there is no difference and both variants are fast.

---

The problem is with conversion to `bool`, not with inlining. The destructor of the following form causes the same problem:

```
~String() { if ((bool)(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(data_) & 1) == false) delete data_; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this code:

```
if (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(data_) & 1 == 0) delete data_;
```

it can be optimized out entirely:  `1 == 0` is always `0`, and `x & 0` is always false for all `x`.  The first case is slower because it is actually doing something.

I suppose you meant:

```
if ( (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(data_) & 1) == 0) delete data_;
```

---

A mnemonic I use for precedence of `&` `|` is to recall that in precursors of C, there were not separate operators `&` and `&&`;  the `&` operator fulfilled both roles (and you manually convert to boolean range if you wanted a logical comparison). So `x == y & z == w` was normal code for checking if those two equalities held.

When `&&` was introduced, in order to avoid breaking existing code, `&&` was given lower precedence than `&`; but `&` remained unchanged, below `==`.

The C++ language did not alter these precedences either, presumably this was purposeful to minimize incompatibilities between the two languages.

Comment: Deleted my answer because it was wrong; this is the right answer.

Comment: Agree, my bad, such a simple mistake :). Anyway, it makes me wonder whether this is the reason for different implementations of SSO in libstdc++ and libc++. Libc++ seems to be more memory-efficient (`sizeof(std::string)` is 24 and capacity for SSO is 22) than libstdc++ (size if 32 and capacity only 15; the same holds for MSVC). However, in the latter case, short strings can be simply tested by comparing 2 pointers, so there are no bitwise operations involved.